"I am nothing" is the epitome of humility. Why not "I am worse than nothing"?
The gemara in Chullin records a beautiful teaching of Rabbi Eliezer son of Rabbi Yossi HaGalili:

אמר רבי יוחנן משום רבי אלעזר בר' שמעון כל מקום שאתה מוצא דבריו של רבי
אליעזר בנו של רבי יוסי הגלילי בהגדה עשה אזניך כאפרכסת (דברים ז, ז) לא
מרבכם מכל העמים חשק ה' בכם וגו' אמר להם הקדוש ברוך הוא לישראל חושקני
בכם שאפילו בשעה שאני משפיע לכם גדולה אתם ממעטין עצמכם לפני נתתי גדולה
לאברהם אמר לפני (בראשית יח, כז) ואנכי עפר ואפר למשה ואהרן אמר (שמות
טז, ז) ונחנו מה לדוד אמר (תהלים כב, ז) ואנכי תולעת ולא איש ... אמר רבא
ואיתימא ר' יוחנן גדול שנאמר במשה ואהרן יותר ממה שנאמר באברהם דאילו
באברהם כתיב ואנכי עפר ואפר ואילו במשה ואהרן כתיב ונחנו מה
Rabbi Yoḥanan says in the name of Rabbi Elazar, son of Rabbi Shimon:
Any place where you find the statements of Rabbi Eliezer, son of Rabbi
Yosei HaGelili, in reference to aggada, make your ears like a funnel.
As Rabbi Eliezer interpreted the verse: “Not because you are more in
number than any people did the Lord desire you and choose you, for you
were the fewest of all peoples” (Deuteronomy 7:7), as follows: The
Holy One, Blessed be He, said to the Jewish people: I desire you,
since even at a time that I bestow greatness upon you, you diminish,
i.e., humble, yourselves before Me. I granted greatness to Abraham,
yet he said before Me: “And I am but dust and ashes” (Genesis 18:27).
I granted greatness to Moses and Aaron, yet Moses said of the two of
them: “And what are we” (Exodus 16:7). I granted greatness to David,
yet he said: “But I am a worm, and no man” (Psalms 22:7) ... The
Gemara relates: Rava says, and some say Rabbi Yoḥanan says: Greater
is that which is stated with regard to Moses and Aaron than that
which is stated with regard to Abraham. As with regard to Abraham it
is written: “And I am but dust and ashes,” while with regard to Moses
and Aaron it is written: “And what are we,” i.e., we are not even dust
and ashes [Steinsalz translation, and commentary, slightly edited].

This famous passage records how these giants described themselves as "small" or "nothing", all of which attributes tremendous humility to them. Rava (some say Rabbi Yochanan) even shows that the "lesser" the metaphor they use, the more humble they are (at least comparing Avraham and Moshe/Aharon).
My question is: why is "I am nothing" the humblest? There is such a concept as "I am worse than nothing" i.e. "the world is worse off because of me".
Even on Yom Kippur, during the end of Shmoneh Esrei where we describe ourselves similarly, in our forefathers' legacy, we don't go below "nothing":

עַד שֶׁלֹּא נוֹצַרְתִּי אֵינִי כְדַאי, וְעַכְשָׁו שֶׁנּוֹצַרְתִּי
כְּאִלּוּ לֹא נוֹצַרְתִּי. עָפָר אֲנִי בְּחַיָּי, קַל וָחֹמֶר
בְּמִיתָתִי.
Before I was formed, I wasn't worthy. Now that I have been formed,
it's as if I haven't been formed. I am dust in life, all the moreso in
death.

Even this morning prayer doesn't go into the "worse than nothing" range, although it introduces quite a lot of versions of describing ourselves as small or nothing, in humility.

 I bet there's a clever and interesting answer. I suspect some of it might be explained by the idea that Jewish humility is defined as being truthful to oneself, and grateful towards the sources of our talents, however, why can't we be honest with ourself and say that we are worse than nothing? Some strong sources seem to hold this way, and surely it is true at least some times and could be considered something we can use in our prayers. A good answer will hopefully deal with this and give a satisfying answer.
I don't really think finding a counter example (or near misses) will be a good way to answer this question. Even if there are counter examples, none of the above sources use them, and all could so that needs to be explained one way or another. 

We also say "What are we?" (in Birchot Hashachar (https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Preparatory_Prayers%2C_Sovereignty_of_Heaven.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and yom kippur davening), albeit in slightly different Hebrew words.

@Banana thanks for helping me sanitize my links. "this morning prayer"'s link was meant to point to that, but I copied the wrong link

If Moshe and Aharon's "what are we" can be interpreted as less than nothing, why can't ours?

@Banana Where is it interpreted as less than nothing? That would undermine my whole question

"While with regard to Moses and Aaron it is written: “And what are we,” i.e., we are not even dust and ashes."

@Banana i.e. nothing at all. Not less than nothing. How do you read it as less than nothing? The whole chiddush of Rava et al is that "dust and ashes" are slightly something

dust and ashes = nothing; less than dust and ashes = less then nothing

The idea that we are less than nothing would imply that we have an independent existence. The whole point of humility is to understand that Hashem is the only independent entity; אין עוד מלּבדּו. We are, in a sense, literally nothing. We are not conventionally worthless; rather, the concept of “worth” does not apply to us. Thus, it’s illogical to pursue selfish ends, as there’s no “self” for you to serve. The only being who can and should logically be served, is Hashem.

@Qwertrl amazing answer

Rashi on the passage you quoted explains that "making yourselves small before Me" is about humility.

Not from your muchness.  Because you do not make much of yourselves,
but rather you make yourselves little.  Therefore He loves you, for
you are little--you make yourselves little in humility.

Sefer Orchot Tzaddikim, Chapter Two (Humility) explains humility as follows:

The root of humility is that one should think, even while he is
healthy and in a state of tranquility, healthy and wealthy, that the
Blessed Creator bestowed this goodness upon him.  He should realize
that he does not deserve it.  He should consider the greatness of G-d
and His exalted splendor and think: what am I?  Am I not a very lowly
creature, existing in a lowly world which itself must come to an end?
He should also think: All the good deeds which I might do are only a
drop in the ocean compared to what I really should do.

As I understand it, this means that the idea of "I am nothing" is that any good that I do is only a consequence of the good that Hashem did for me.  If I have something intelligent to say, Who gave me intelligence?  If I have built valuable and useful institutions, Who gave me the money and the organizational skills and the contacts to do this?  And therefore I cannot take the credit, but must refer the credit back to the true Benefactor.
On the other hand, to say "I am worse than nothing, I am a net drag on the world" is, in the case of any person that learns Hashem's Torah and keeps His mitzvos, a lie.  It furthermore looks rather a lot like accusing the One Above of having erred in creating him in the first place.

I considered this, but it needs more. I can certainly do things that make my own eternal life worse, ch'v, so why can't I make the whole world worse too, ch'v?

I provided sources in an edit.

Our Rabbi spoke about it on Yom Kippur. I will have to ask the source. The words we say during Shemoneh Esrei "Before I was formed, I wasn't worthy. Now that I have been formed, it's as if I haven't been formed. I am dust in life, all the moreso in death," are dealing with a specific mission that Hashem assigns to each and everyone of us. Before we are born we do not know if we will fulfill this mission and now that we are living, we may not know if we are any close to fulfilling this mission. Therefore, Moshe and Aharon's words can be seen quite inline with this specific statement: "What are we?" - i.e. if our actions in this world were bad, we are worse off than at the time we were born; or if we did the mitzvos - did they bring one close to the accomplishment of the mission we had to do?
In the Gemara there is an important additional meaning in the words of Avraham as explained by Netziv's Haemek Davar Bereshis 18:27. The commentary Tosefes Bracha (different from the well known Torah Temimah) by R. Barukh Epstein connects the words of Netziv to those of Moshe and Aharon:

ומושה ואהרון, בבטולם את ערך עצמם, אמרו "ונחנו מה" (שמות ט"ז ח).
ואפשר לכוין שתי המליצות (אפר ועפר - ונחנו מה) כי נאמרו למשל, לפי מצב וערך אומריהן, כי לעפר ואפר יש תוצאות הפכיות. כי העפר ניכר שבחה לאחר שעבדוה ותוציא צמחה. וכנגדה - האפר, הי' ששבחו קודם שנעשה לאבק דק, אז כשהי' עץ או מין אחר שמוציאין ממנו אש. כמו שחשיב במשנה ביצה ל"ג א', אבל מי שנעשה אפר אינו כלום. ועל זה המשיל אברהם את עצמו ביחס גדולי דורות לשניהם, כי כעפר אין לו זכות מיקודם לו, דהיינו זכות אבות, וכאפר - שאין לו זכות אחריו, זכות בנים שברא מזכי אבא (סנהדרין ק"ד א'). וזה נאמר קודם שנולד יצחק - אבל מושה ואהרון  היו לכם זכותי שני הצדדים לפניהם ולאחריהם, זכות אבות וזכות בנים. ולו היו יכולים להמשיל עליהם הפחיתות מן עפר ואפר, כפי הציור הנזכר, והמשילובטולם בהם עצמם, ואמרו - ונחנו (עצמנו) מה.
And Moshe and Aharon, in their tremendous humility, said, "And what are we?" (Exodus 16:8). And it is possible to align the two statements (ash and dust - and what are we?) which were said as an example, according to the situation and value of their words, that dust/soil and ash have opposite meanings. Because the dust/soil shows richness after one had worked on it and brought forth vegetation. And opposite of it - the ashes, that is when it was a tree / wood or anything else that was used for fire, as discussed in Mishnah Beitzah 4:6-7 (or 33a in the gemara), but once it is turned into ashes it is nothing. And this is why Avraham compared himself to the greats of both groups of generations, because as dust/soil he did not have merits (of great people) that had preceded him, i.e. the merits of fathers; and as ash - he did not have merits afterwards, the merit of sons, as the son confers merit upon the father (Sanhedrin 104a). These words were said before Isaac was born. However, Moshe and Aaron had merits on both sides before them and after them, the merits of fathers and the merits of children, and they could not express their humility as dust/soil and ashes, like the described comparison. That is why they just said - and "what are we (ourselves)"?

Perhaps, gemara states that the words of Moshe and Aharon are preferable from this point of view since we, the Jewish people today, always have merits of the previous generations and may we have more children BE"H.
