Why do we say we have no worthy deeds?
We say "we have no worthy deeds" (in Avinu Malkeinu and Tachanun).
Are we disrespecting others and ourselves by saying this?
I think it would make more sense if we said we have few worthy deeds.
Why do we say we have none?

Related, but converse https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/145376/31534

אם צדקת מה תתן לו
